# A good WPF scrolling timeline control? (fancy datetime picker)

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controls, custom-controls

I'm looking for somthing I can use as a timeline control.
A kind of "banner" the user can drag to the left or the right to go forward or backwards
in time and then he or she should be able to select a point in time on that control.

A fancy datetime picker :-)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd love to create one. Give me more specifics of what it should do, and maybe an image of what one might look like.

Comment: @Micah ... darn I never noticed your comments...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one also http://timeline.codeplex.com

Comment: It does make VS2010 crash though

Answer (score 11):

You are welcome to try my new TimelineControl.
I've publish it in codeplex: [TimelineControl](http://timelinecontrol.codeplex.com/)

Ido.

Comment: Hi, I am currently trying to use this timeline control, is there any basic documentation on how to use it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @HelpMePlz, nice to see this work still help you. There is limited docs in the documentation tab, that's about it. https://timelinecontrol.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Hi @IdoRan, I noticed on the codeplex site there is a screenshot of a timeline control test application, is this application on github or anywhere else so that i would be able to understand how to use it better?  Thanks.

Comment: It the application in the MTest project - it stands for Manual Test of the control, you can see there example of how to use the control

Comment: I've copy the project to Github because Codeplex is going down https://github.com/ido-ran/WpfTimelineControl

Answer (score 7):

You can find TimeLine Panels [here](http://www.robzelt.com/blog/2007/01/10/TimeLinePanel+Custom+WPF+Control+Part+1.aspx) and [here](http://www.blendables.com/products/productsLayoutmix.aspx)

And datetime picker [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/wpf-date-time-picker/) , I have personally used the datepicker from Kevin's [Bag O tricks](http://j832.com/bagotricks/)  a lot

Answer (score 2):

There is a datetime picker and month calendar on the [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15598).

Comment: As far as I can tell the WPF Toolkit only has a Date Picker, not a DateTime Picker.And the Date Picker isn't production ready as it has a memory leak, read the Tips and Tricks

Comment: The memory leak was subsequently fixed, but well after Scott's comment.  http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/22567