# WPF Timeline Control

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a WPF Timeline User Control.  I have checked out Blendables Timeline and Animated Timeline control from IdentityMine, but it is rather basic and buggy.  I am looking for a timeline control that is similar to the MIT Similie timeline.

http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/

What i need to be able to do is add interactive objects to the timeline, for example video, images, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Asked this question before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333948/a-good-wpf-scrolling-timeline-control-fancy-datetime-picker

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good WPF scrolling timeline control? (fancy datetime picker)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333948/a-good-wpf-scrolling-timeline-control-fancy-datetime-picker)

Answer (score 3):

http://timeline.codeplex.com. Try it.